# Django Sitemap for many sub-sites

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I have a app that creates websites for users. Each website has many sections, all with their own URL.

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to build a sitemap for this app.

1. I can successfully create one massive sitemap.xml file that lists all the links for the entire site. But this is over 100,000 urls.
2. Another idea is to create a sitemap.xml for each individual website hosted on my app. So app.com/sitemap.xml would be a map of all the websites (app.com/website) and then app.com/website/sitemap.xml would be a sitemap of all the links

If I do #2, how would I create that using django's sitemap tool?  The docs have helped with with #1, but I can't figure out #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Subclass the `Sitemap` class to provide your own `Sitemap` implementation that will be referenced by your "parent" `Sitemap`. Take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#a-simple-example) for an example. Also, you'll have to generate a `Sitemap` index, as described [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index)